# Find parent id of product in magento

Tags: magento

here is my code.

```
 $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) 
    {//how to find parent id here}
```

At the above mentioned comment I want to access parent id of that particular product.
Please Help ..

Comment: Isn't $item->getParentId() working ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below code, may be it will help you

```
if($item->getTypeId() == "simple"){
    $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($item->getId()); // check for grouped product
    if(!$parentIds)
        $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($item->getId()); //check for config product

}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but I need help when we do it will above code.In sort I want to find parent id of a product added in cart.

Comment: actually just managed the solution.Here is the code.. $session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
  foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item)
   {
     echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($item->getProduct()->
   getCategoryIds($item->getProductId()))->getId();
   }

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to get the parent

```
foreach(...) {
    $parents = $item->getTypeInstance()->getParentIdsByChild($item->getId());
    //if you need to load the parent
    if(!empty($parents)) {
        $parentProd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parents[0]);
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this might help you:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->load($productId);
$grouped_product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped');
$groupedParentId = $grouped_product_model->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
```

Comment: Or not.. What if someone is using grouped products and a product has multiple parents? :)